# checking for an existence of a key in postgresql jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in postgres db. I need to query for an existence of specific key "ssn" in the json stored in the column. This key is not a top level key, but is nested. I wrote a query similar to below but it doesn't seem to retrieve the appropriate columns -

```
select * from application where content ? 'ssn';
```

When I run the above query with top level keys , it works.

```
{  
   "name":"bob",
   "business":{  
      "ssn":"XXXXXXXX",
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of json that is not retrieved by this query?

Comment: @IvanMogila added a sample. actual payload is much larger

Answer (score 2):

If you know all possible locations of ssn key you can use query:

```
select *
from application
where content #> '{business,ssn}' is not null
  or content #> '{whatever,deep,ssn}' is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. I just added additional question under Haleemur's answer.

Answer (score 2):

use a extract-element-at-path operator [`#>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and check whether the value at the given path is null.

example:

```
WITH test(col) AS (
SELECT UNNEST(
  ARRAY['{"name": "bob", "business": {"ssn": "abcd"}}'::jsonb, 
        '{"name": "jen", "business": {"ssn": "1234"}}',   
        '{"name": "kay", "nonprofit": {"no-ssn": "no-ssn"}}'
        '{"name": "todd", "business": {"no-ssn": "no-ssn"}}']
))
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE col#>>'{business, ssn}' IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Haleemjur Ali. This works fine for the example , but doesn't work in a scenario say where business element is an array under another root element. How can I handle arrays as part of this query?

Comment: add a better example, if you want help making a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

you

1. either have to write the recursive query to parse the structure of json and check for the key in every branch,
2. or simply match pattern against text representation of jsonb

smth like:

```
select * from application 
where content::text like '%"ssn":%';
```